# Add CorrelationId to remote calls in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I use Delgating handler to add correlation ids to inward requests to my application.

But, my MVC app makes frequent calls to remote domain *https://remoteservice.net/xyz* via an webapi client provided by them. The remote service API allows users to set correlation id via request header, but the webapi client doesn't provide a way to expose that.

So I am now thinking to set correlation id via owin pipeline for all outgoing remote calls from my MVC app. Is this possible? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend an HttpClientHandler and add a correlationId header there:

```
public class CorrelatingHandler : HttpClientHandler
 {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("currelationId", Guid.NewGuid());

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
 }



using(var client = new HttpClient(new CorrelatingHandler())){
  .....
}
```

source: https://forums.asp.net/post/6025521.aspx